# Request with two different dates ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I've a little issue with MySQL for making a request with two different dates ranges.

I need to have **nb_sales** and **last_sales** until 2014 but **frequence** only for the past year.

The result I want :

```
customer_id     |    nb_sales    |   last_sales  |   frequence
---------------------------------------------------------------
Customer ID     | Sales make by  |  How many days|  How many sales
                |  the customer  |  since the    |  has been made
                |                |  last sales?  |  this year?
```

Column 1-3 are in the first date range : today to 2014 
Column 4 is in a seconde date range : today to y-1

So I tried to  :

1. Create a temporary table and insert **frequence**
2. `SELECT` **customer_id**, **nb_sales**, **last_sales** and **frequence** with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

The first step is ok but for the second one I don't have any result or error message... And this happened when I wanted to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` my temporary table:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_frequence 
  ON tmp_frequence.client_id = sales_flat_order.customer_id
```

Maybe you have a better idea?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_frequence (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id INT,
    frequence INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tmp_frequence (client_id, frequence)
SELECT sales_flat_order.customer_id, COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id)
FROM sales_flat_order
WHERE sales_flat_order.created_at BETWEEN '2014-05-22 00:00:00' and '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY sales_flat_order.customer_id;

/* ------------------------------  */ 
SELECT  
-- * , 
sales_flat_order.customer_id customer_id,
COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id) nb_sales,
DATEDIFF("2017-07-31",DATE_FORMAT(MAX(sales_flat_order_item.created_at),"%Y-%m-%d")) last_sales,
tmp_frequence.frequence frequence

FROM adl_ec.sales_flat_order_item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_flat_order 
  ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_frequence 
  ON tmp_frequence.client_id=sales_flat_order.customer_id

WHERE sales_flat_order_item.created_at BETWEEN '2014-05-22 00:00:00' and '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY customer_id;

DROP TABLE tmp_frequence ;
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "temporality," but your `WHERE` clause is transforming your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  The conditions of the outer table need to be included in the `ON` clause for the outer join, since the `WHERE` clause is executed *after* the `NULL` results from the outer join are returned.  Other than that, I really have no idea what you're trying to do to offer any help...

Comment: need to see data sample (and expected results)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is "working"? What is this code supposed to do? Please read & act on [mcve]. Image that you need to explain everything to us because we have no idea what you are talking about --because we don't. Also "making a request with two temporality" doesn't make sense. Also read textbook definitions of inner join & left join.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my english ... I've edited the post with the information you tell me. Maybe it's more clear now ?

Comment: you have a `Space` in your `WHERE` at `sales_flat_order_item .created_at ` is this true for your actual query as well?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord unfortunatly it's not the case in my actual query

Comment: please make sure the example code accurately reflects the real query, otherwise people are going to point out false problems like this instead of being able to focus on the real issue.

Comment: @ADyson yes, I'm really sorry about it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Finally found a solution.
Thank you really for your help :)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_frequence;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_frequence (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id INT,   
    recence INT,
    frequence INT,
    montant INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tmp_frequence (client_id, frequence)
SELECT sales_flat_order.customer_id, COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id)
FROM sales_flat_order
WHERE sales_flat_order.created_at BETWEEN '2016-07-31 00:00:00' and '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY sales_flat_order.customer_id;


INSERT INTO tmp_frequence (client_id, recence, montant)
SELECT
sales_flat_order.customer_id,
DATEDIFF("2017-07-31",DATE_FORMAT(MAX(sales_flat_order_item.created_at),"%Y-%m-%d")) recence,
COUNT(sales_flat_order.grand_total) montant

FROM adl_ec.sales_flat_order_item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_flat_order ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id 
AND sales_flat_order_item.created_at BETWEEN '2014-05-22 00:00:00' and '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
AND qty_invoiced >0
AND sales_flat_order_item.sku NOT LIKE '%abo%'
AND sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered < 5

GROUP BY customer_id;

SELECT tmp_frequence.client_id,MAX(tmp_frequence.recence) Recence,MAX(tmp_frequence.frequence) Frequence,MAX(tmp_frequence.montant) Montant
FROM tmp_frequence 
GROUP BY tmp_frequence.client_id;
```